# How can a unit test confirm an exception has been thrown

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, exception

Im writing a unit test for a c# class, One of my tests should cause the method to throw an exception when the data is added. How can i use my unit test to confirm that the exception has been thrown?

Comment: What unit testing framework?

Comment: the standard unit testing system that comes with visual studio, im not sure if it has a specific name

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on what unit test framework you're using. In *all* cases you could do something like:

```
[Test]
public void MakeItGoBang()
{
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     try
     {
         foo.Bang();
         Assert.Fail("Expected exception");
     }
     catch (BangException)
     { 
         // Expected
     }
}
```

In some frameworks there's an attribute you can add to the test method to express the expected exception, or there may be a method, such as:

```
[Test]
public void MakeItGoBang()
{
     Foo foo = new Foo();
     Assert.Throws<BangException>(() => foo.Bang());
}
```

It's nicer to limit the scope like this, as if you apply it to the whole test, the test could pass even if the *wrong* line threw the exception.

Comment: The first approach isn't great as it doesn't Assert in the codepath that throws an exception.  A good test always needs to assert that some expectation happened.  I'd prefer to either set a flag in the catch block or save off the exception in a local variable to assert on at the end.

Comment: @Brian: The assertion is implicit in the fact that we don't reach the Assert.Fail (so *an* exception has been thrown) and only the right exception is caught (so another exception can't have been thrown instead). I don't have a problem with this style at all - it makes it pretty clear what's expected IMO. I prefer `Assert.Throws` in terms of compactness though. Note that if you need to check any other details of the exception, you can easily do that within the catch block.

Comment: I agree that Assert.Throws is ideal.  And although it still is pretty trivial to decipher that not reaching an assert.Fail() means the test passes, I think given the option between the approach in the answer and an approach where you save off the exception and Assert on it after the catch block articulate the intent of the test more clearly.  Ultimately, it's a style choice and, perhaps more importantly, a cry out to Microsoft to improve their assert functionality to be competitive with other frameworks out there.

Comment: @Brian: It's definitely a style choice - I really don't like the "saving the exception" approach myself, but I can see how it's appealing to those who make everything follow an AAA approach.

Comment: Of course, even if your framework doesn't support it, implementing `Assert.Throws<>` is trivial...

Comment: Failing a test in a `try` block is an interesting way. Although it is not suitable to *Don’t Make Me Think* approach, it is a concise way to get the job done without using any library. Actually this must not be a surprise since here the aim is the opposite of a regular unit test: Showing an exception is being thrown.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin: I fail to see why "showing an exception is being thrown" is the opposite of a regular unit test. I very frequently write tests to check that exceptions are being thrown as expected - which is why most unit test frameworks, at least for .NET, *do* have `Assert.Throws`. (I'd also say that "don't make me think" is generally not something I aim for. Indeed, in Noda Time my philosophy is precisely the opposite - I aim to force developers to think enough to make appropriate decisions, then make those decisions easy to express. Software development shouldn't be thought-free.)

Comment: Writing tests verifying that exceptions are thrown is a normal practice for me, too. There is no problem with that or using `Assert.Throws()`. Using `Assert.Throws()` already expresses its purpose in a comprehensible way at a first glance. Now let me rephrase what I mean: Thinking in a more general sense, there is a *reverse situation* in the first solution since the normal path is the catch block and the *exceptional* path is the try block in this code.

Comment: With regard to the Don’t Make Me Think approach, I aggree that this one is not particularly for programmers and is mainly for end users. But I find applying this rule to programming *as much as possible* useful. A basic example is preferring the explicit `b = b + 1; a = b;` statements instead of the compact but confusing pre-increment operator `a = ++b`. But this is not applicable to your situation of course.

Answer (score 13):

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(System.Exception))]
```

for Visual Studio Unit Testing Framework.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.expectedexceptionattribute.aspx):

> The test method will pass if the expected exception is thrown.
>
> The test will fail if the thrown exception inherits from the expected exception.

Comment: This has the unfortunate property that it will pass if the exception is thrown *anywhere* within the method though - not just where you expect it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to follow the triple-A pattern (arrange, act, assert), you could go for this, regardless of test framework:

```
[Test]
public void MyMethod_DodgyStuffDone_ThrowsRulesException() {

    // arrange
    var myObject = CreateObject();
    Exception caughtException = null;

    // act
    try {
        myObject.DoDodgyStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        caughtException = ex;
    }

    // assert
    Assert.That(caughtException, Is.Not.Null);
    Assert.That(caughtException, Is.TypeOf<RulesException>());
    Assert.That(caughtException.Message, Is.EqualTo("My Error Message"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Nunit, you can tag your test with

```
[ExpectedException( "System.ArgumentException" ) )]
```

Comment: I don't like this answer, because it makes the test pass even if that exception is throw where you don't expect it.

Comment: @abatishchev if you - for example - invoke three distinct method in your test, this attribute just makes sure that an ArgumentException has to be raisen somewhere, but maybe you want to be sure that ArgumentException is thrown only by one of these three methods call.

Comment: Well you said that know that your test throws and exception, and you want to test that, right?

Comment: No, you typically want to test that *one particular operation* throws an exception. The test shouldn't pass if something else throws the exception. I also don't like the way that the exception type is specified as a string instead of using `typeof(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can usee Verify() method for Unit Testing and compare your Exception Message from return type.

```
InterfaceMockObject.Verify(i =>i.Method(It.IsAny<>())), "Your received Exception Message");
```

You need to write some classname or datatype in It.IsAny<> block