# Negative tests - should I expect the exact exception?

Tags: c#, testing

Consider the following method

```
public void Foo(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("str");

    if (str.Length != 5)
        throw new MyException();
}
```

Suppose I want to write a negative test for it like so:

```
public void TestFoo()
{
    try
    {
        Foo(null); //this could be an remote call (e.g. WCF)
        Assert.Fail("Expected ArgumentNullException");
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException) {} //should this be "Exception" instead?

    try
    {
        Foo("four"); //this could be an remote call (e.g. WCF)
        Assert.Fail("Expected MyException");
    }
    catch (MyException) {} //should this be "Exception" instead?
}
```

It seems to me that catching a specific exception as above is an implementation detail, which may make the test brittle and too coupled with the implementation (rather than the interface). Obviously `MyException` could change one day, but even `ArgumentNullException` may be, say,  wrapped inside some other exception (for example by a future WCF behavior). Typically the test knows that *"four"* should fail, and that's all it cares about - failure.

The exception to this (no pun intended) would perhaps be cases where the exception is translated into something that is passed on to the user, such as user-friendly messages (e.g. `UserNameTakenException` which is mapped to *user name already taken, try a different one*). In such cases you'd want to make sure the correct error is conveyed. Even then it's a little problematic since it would mean a different type of exception for each possible user error, but that may not be too bad (usually there aren't many of those).

Does my line of thinking make sense ? Should I indeed catch the generic `Exception` in test cases that don't involve user-facing exceptions ?

Comment: you don't catch exceptions in TestFoo.  You attribute the method with the expected exception.

Comment: You might get flak for being opinion-based, but in my mind it makes perfect sense - the exceptions being thrown in particular situations is part of the contract of the method call/API and as such should be guarded by tests.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the testing framework though...  such as: Assert.Throws<MyException>(() => wmd.DoItNow());

Comment: Yes, you should check for the specific type of the exception (as closely as the contract specifies). Otherwise you may be hiding defects. And in most test frameworks you have better built-in support for this.

Comment: See how Jon Skeet did it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6125143/how-can-a-unit-test-confirm-an-exception-has-been-thrown

Comment: If your code throws an exception, then it should be tested. If your code allows an uncaught exception, then it does not need to be tested. Something that I use as a key indicator is whether I should include the exception as part of the triple-slash documentation. If I throw it, I need to document it, and therefore I need to test it.

Comment: Thanks all - you've answered my question, please write it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 3):

Simply write at least 4 tests:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
public void TestFooForNull()
{
    Foo(null);
}


[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(MyException))]
public void TestFooForInvalidSizeTooShort()
{
    Foo("1234");
}


[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(MyException))]
public void TestFooForInvalidSizeTooLong()
{
    Foo("123456");
}


[Test]
public void TestFoo()
{
    Foo("12345");
}
```

When writing unit tests, it's best to treat one particular case per test.

Comment: Roy, thanks for the answer, and separation may very well be the better choice here, but it is not the issue. Implicitly from your code though I gather you support the view that the exact exception should be expected, which is inline to the other responses received.

Answer (score 0):

```
  > should I expect the exact exception?
  > ...
  > Should I indeed catch the generic Exception in test cases that 
  > don't involve user-facing exceptions ?
```

In dotnet it is not a good idea to catch the generic `Exception` because that would catch the AssertionException, too. I assume that it is the same with java, too

```
public void ThisTestWillNeverFail()
{
    try
    {
        Assert.Fail("some error message");
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {
    } 
}
```